# Swift3 class UIButton

Tags: xcode, swift

Добрый день
раньше создавал класс кнопки так:

```html
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches as! Set<UITouch>, with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches as! Set<UITouch>, with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches as! Set<UITouch>, with: event)
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<NSObject>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches as! Set<UITouch>, with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

теперь на каждую строчку выдает ошибку

Comment: вот вообще на каждую?

Comment: ну и ошибку посмотреть было бы неплохо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в курсе, что в xcode есть автокомлит, и можно начать печатать название метода, чтобы получить его новую подпись?

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches , with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches , with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches , with: event)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

touchesMoved убрал, поскольку он у вас все равно ничего не делает